Material UI Datagrid font too small
Anywhere I see Material UI DataGrid has normal fonts, but when I tried it the fonts in the DataGrid were too small. For the rows and headers I managed to increase the fonts but for the pagination side the fonts and the icons are too small.
Preview of small font
Here is the component for the image above:
<DataGrid
  autoHeight={false}
  columns={columns}
  rows={rows}
  initialState={{
    pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 5 } },
  }}
  pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 50]}
/>

I tried using sx styling in DataGrid but didn't change anything
<DataGrid
  sx={{
    "& .css-rtrcn9-MuiTablePagination-root": {
      fontSize: "24",
    }
  }}
  autoHeight={false}
  columns={columns}
  rows={rows}
  initialState={{
    pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 5 } },
  }}
  pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 50]}
/>

Has anyone faced this error before? This is my first time using Material UI.
Maybe I missed some library.
